# Open orbits in the space of symmetric matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

I have the following statement and I want to know if it's true or not.

> The orbit set of symmetric matrices of rank 2 is open in the space of symmetric matrices of size $2$×$2$.

The group action that's defined in this question is given by $S\to ASA^T$ where $A$ is invertible matrix of size $2\times 2$ and $S$ is a square symmetric matrix of the same size.

I saw somewhere that it's true but I am not sure why ? I searched about open sets in the spaces of symmetric matrices so that i could prove it myself but I am not familiar with normed topology yet so I couldn't understand much about the prove . If there is a prove where I don't need norms( normed topology) It will be really helpful.

Comment: What you "learned" was false; the diffeomorphism is between $n \times n$ symmetric spaces and $\Bbb R^k$, where $k = \frac12 n(n+1)$. One such diffeomorphism sends the coordinates of the euclidean point $(x_1, \ldots, x_k)$ to the $k$ entries in the upper triangle of the symmetric matrix. For $2 \times 2$ matrices, for example, the map is $(a, b, c) \mapsto \pmatrix{a & b \\ b & c}$, where the lower-left $b$ is "forced" by the upper-right entry being $b$. You can probably generalize from this example.

Comment: What makes you think that this claim is true? (It fails once the dimension is at least 3.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Well, I meant for the case $n$=2. I was studying for general case but I came up with this statement while working on the case $n$=2. I  have edited my post.

Comment: Add $2\times 2$ to the main statement.

Comment: This is better but your question is still a bit unclear: Are you asking if this is true that the orbit of **every** rank 2 matrix is open? This will be indeed true. A hint: prove  that there are three such orbits: One consisting of positive-definite matrices, one of indefinite invertible matrices and one of negative-definite matrices.  Did you learn the classification of quadratic forms in two variables in your linear algebra class (or the analytic geometry class)? If not, you should.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know that there are positive, negative and indefinite orbits of rank 2 . I already have orbit structures with me but what I don't have is the reason why , for example the orbit set of  negative definite symmetric matrices is open? My intuition said it's true because taking any small perturbation of the entries will still give me negative definite matrix but i am not able to formalize it, since i have narrow knowledge in normed topology and I haven't studied yet about quadratic forms.

Comment: @Lana_2001 Do you know that eigenvalues depend continuously on the matrix coefficients?